# Redirect to thank you page after calling curl post function using submit button

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, curl

So i was working on a php web application. Here is the form(trackit.php) i am working on.

```
<?php
function curlPOST($fields) {
$url = 'http://example.com/mailit4.php';

    //url-ify the data for the POST^M
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
$lid = $_GET["lid"];
$list_id = $_GET["list_id"];
$phone=$_GET["phone"];
/*
$filename = 'leadids.txt';
$contents = file($filename);
$myfile = fopen("leadids.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
*/
$fields = array('lid' => $lid, 'list_id' => $list_id, 'phone'=> $phone);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Client Appreciation Weekend 2016</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>


<table width="986" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/example" alt="example.com" width="600" height="133" style="margin-left:180px;" border="0" usemap="#Map" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>



<table width="986" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


          <form action="<?curlPOST($fields)?>" method="post" >
          <tr>
                <td>
            <label>Phonenumber:</label>
            </td>

                <input  type="hidden" name="lid" id="lid" size="40" value= "<?=$lid?>"> 
                <input  type="hidden" name="list_id" id="list_id" size="40" value= "<?=$list_id?>"> 
                <td >
                <input  type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber"  size="40" value= "<?=$phone?>"> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>

            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit Data"> 
            </td>
            </tr>

          </form>

</table>







</body>
</html>
?>
```

I am posting these three values to mailit4.php using curl post. When i click submit it calls that function and run mailit4.php script which is on the other server. Everything is working fine but when i am trying to redirect my page to thanks.html which is on this server(where trackit.php is). Its doing nothing. Can  anyone please how i can redirect to thanks.html

here is my code for mailit4.php

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'example', 'example', 'example');


$lid = $_POST['lid'];
$list_id = $_POST['list_id'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];

$sql = "SELECT list_id FROM exampleWHERE lead_id=$lid";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$value = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if ($value[0] != $list_id){
$body = "Leadid " . $lid . " : " . $list_id . "\n\n";
$subject = "Zombie Drip:" . $lid . " : " . $list_id;

mail("example@gmail.com", $subject, $body); 
}
$query = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE example SET list_id=$list_id,called_since_last_reset='N',phone_number=$phone WHERE lead_id=$lid");
if($query){
header('Location: http://example.com/thanks.html/');
exit;
} 
else{

$body = "Leadid " . $lid . " : " . $list_id . "\n\n";
$subject = "It could not update the example due to some reasons " .$query ;
mail("example@gmail.com", $subject, $body);




}
```

?>

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you post this question already ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not working perfectly as `<form action="<?curlPOST($fields)?>" method="post" >` is wrong.

you are not echoing `curlPOST($fields)` so the when you are loading this page, your `mailit4.php` is loading one time and the action of this form are set to self like `<form action="" method="post" >` and you are thinking your code is working as each time you submit it calles this page as well as `mailit4.php`. your correct action will be `<form action="" method="post" >` and put this code after calling  function `curlPOST`
    if(!empty($_POST)) curlPOST($fields);

another problem in your code is,

```
$lid = $_GET["lid"];
$list_id = $_GET["list_id"];
$phone=$_GET["phone"];
```

method of your form is `post` and you are trying to catch this data by `get`

in your `mailit4.php` you are using mail means you are sending data to somewhere that means, data flushed already, and then you are calling header. instate use `file_get_contents()` to get contents of `thanks.html` as this script will not out anything to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please return something from your mailit4.php like

```
If(mail($subject....))
{ 
    echo "ok";
}
```

And in your curl function

```
If( $result == "ok" )
{
       // redirect to thank you page
}
```

I am giving idea with little description because i am typing from my mobile

Hope it will help you

Thanks